# Jeep not starting -- two solenoids?

Tags: starter, mitsubishi, solenoid

I have a 2008 1800cc 24V Japanese military jeep ([Mitsubishi Type 73 Light Truck (Shin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Type_73_Light_Truck#Second_generation)) in the Philippines. It has almost always taken multiple clicks of the ignition to get the engine started. The starter normally turns a fraction with each click of the ignition but then stops turning. Sometimes it just clicks. Once I shorted the solenoid terminals with a screwdriver and it would fire immediately every time. I took it to someone who claimed to know something about them. He replaced the ignition switch but still the same. It's 4 years later and has always started eventually. Recently it's been taking longer than the maximum of 10 clicks to start so I just replaced the solenoid in the starter bay. Still the same. I climbed under and looked at the starter motor - it's very difficult to get to, but it looks as if there's another solenoid on top of the starter which isn't easy to get out.
I tried shorting the engine bay solenoids again but it's the same as using the ignition now. The batteries are full and battery terminals have been checked of course.

In Australia, I've owned Fords all my life which were easy to deal with, but this beats me, especially when it's impossible to find anyone who knows what they are doing here. Could there be 2 solenoids on this Jeep? Any suggestions? I do know about waiting 7 seconds (there's a signal click) before starting.

I made up a continuity light to test the solenoid on the starter. There's power to the positive terminal of the solenoid. When I connect to the activation terminal and activate the starter, the light comes on, both while the starter gives an initial movement, and continues while I hold the ignition on start without it turning.

When I activate the starter and the starter turns momentarily, it glows weakly, but then goes out when it stops turning with the starter still activated. I guess it's a problem with the solenoid on the starter. However, when the starter finally starts the jeep, the light glows brightly, indicating good voltage I suppose.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  I don't know much about those in specific.  Is there a specific make/model?  A quick Google search suggests it might be one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Type_73_Light_Truck#Second_generation)?

Comment: Yes, it does look like those, but the worse for wear though. It's a 2008 model used by the Japanese military.I just did some extra testing which I added to my original question.

Comment: I did another test on the output of the solenoid that's on the starter. When I activate the starter and the starter turns momentarily, it glows weakly, but then goes out when it stops turning with the starter still activated. I guess it's a problem with the solenoid on the starter.

Comment: Ah, but when the starter finally starts the jeep, the light glows brightly, indicating good voltage I suppose.

Comment: Wow that beats me.  I've never heard of a car with two starter solenoids.  Can you tell where the repeated clicking is coming from?  Is it from the engine bay solenoid or the one next to the starter?  (And it's not just one click each time you turn the key, right?  It's a bunch of clicks until you let the key off?)  Also, are you sure that's actually a solenoid on the starter?  Usually how it works is there's one solenoid in the engine bay and the starter is connected to that and to power/ground (I don't remember which is normal).

Comment: If there's just one click per key turn, it's probably the starter itself.  A bunch of clicks indicates a bad battery or a bad solenoid.  (Or bad wiring between places, but it sounds like that's fine since it usually starts.)  Does it start strong when it does start?  Or is is a weak I-barely-have-enough-power start?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've since found it's a lightweight relay in the engine bay and a solenoid on the starter. I've been used to old Fords - my V8 had a solenoid on the sidewall and the straight 6 had it integrated into the starter. It starts really strong when it does go as I think I verified with the really bright continuity light. It mostly clicks and turns the engine just a bit weakly with the 24v light barely glowing. I think the click is from the starter solenoid. I removed the starter today and the solenoid terminals were loose. I tightened them but still the same.

Comment: Yeah, I'd suggest just replacing that solenoid.  Hopefully that won't be too difficult if you've gotten the starter out already.  Make sure you post an answer here once you get it figured out!  I'd love to hear what finally fixes it

Comment: Unfortunately, the starter is in 3 parts - I only got the first 2 out - the motor itself. The solenoid is on the final part, almost against the jeep floor under the driver's feet. I can't get to the top bolt. There are 2 screws holding it on but I can't turn the screws - too tight in a tight space. There's an 18 bolt plate covering half the middle of the floor with the 3 gear levers and hand brake mechanism coming through - I could raise that or cut a hole in the jeep floor - UGH. I'll let you know what happens. I doubt if I'll be able to get a new solenoid here.